# Azure REST API does not return encryption settings for Virtual Machine

Tags: rest, azure, encryption, azure-virtual-machine

I have a 16.04-LTS Ubuntu Virtual Machine in my Azure account and I am trying `Azure Disk Encryption` for this virtual machine making use of [this azure cli sample script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/scripts/virtual-machines-linux-cli-sample-encrypt-vm). On running the encryption script, the azure portal shows its OS disk is encrypted. There is `Enabled` under Encryption header.
[image]

However, the Azure REST API ([api link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/virtualmachines-get)) for getting information about the virtual machine does not return the `encryptionSettings` under `properties.storageProfile.osDisk`. I tried both `Model View` and `Model View and Instance View` for the api-version `2017-03-30` as well as `2017-12-01`. Here is the partial response from the API:

```
{
    "name": "ubuntu",
    "properties": {
        "osProfile": {},
        "networkProfile": {},
        "storageProfile": {
            "imageReference": {
                "sku": "16.04-LTS",
                "publisher": "Canonical",
                "version": "latest",
                "offer": "UbuntuServer"
            },
            "osDisk": {
                "name": "ubuntu-OsDisk",
                "diskSizeGB": 30,
                "managedDisk": {
                    "storageAccountType": "Premium_LRS",
                    "id": "..."
                },
                "caching": "ReadWrite",
                "createOption": "FromImage",
                "osType": "Linux"
            },
            "dataDisks": []
        },
        "diagnosticsProfile": {},
        "vmId": "",
        "hardwareProfile": {
            "vmSize": "Standard_B1s"
        },
        "provisioningState": "Succeeded"
    },
    "location": "eastus",
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
    "id": ""
}
```

But for my other encrypted windows virtual machine, I get the correct response which contains `encryptionSettings` in `properties.storageProfile.osDisk`:

```
{
    "name": "win1",
    "properties": {
        "osProfile": {},
        "networkProfile": {},
        "storageProfile": {
            "imageReference": {
                "sku": "2016-Datacenter-smalldisk",
                "publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
                "version": "latest",
                "offer": "WindowsServer"
            },
            "osDisk": {
                "name": "win1_OsDisk_1",
                "diskSizeGB": 31,
                "managedDisk": {
                    "storageAccountType": "Premium_LRS",
                    "id": "..."
                },
                "encryptionSettings": {
                    "diskEncryptionKey": {
                        "secretUrl": "...",
                        "sourceVault": {
                            "id": "..."
                        }
                    },
                    "keyEncryptionKey": {
                        "keyUrl": "...",
                        "sourceVault": {
                            "id": "..."
                        }
                    },
                    "enabled": true
                },
                "caching": "ReadWrite",
                "createOption": "FromImage",
                "osType": "Windows"
            },
            "dataDisks": []
        },
        "diagnosticsProfile": {},
        "vmId": "...",
        "hardwareProfile": {
            "vmSize": "Standard_B1s"
        },
        "provisioningState": "Succeeded"
    },
    "location": "eastus",
    "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
    "id": "..."
}
```

Why is the Virtual Machine Get API not returning the `encryptionSettings` for some VMs? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Encryption completed in about 3 minutes. It has already been over an hour after the encryption.

Comment: no, thats not how it works ;) you should check extension state, it will tell you encryption is in progress

Comment: You mean, if the `provisioning` for the extension `AzureDiskEncryptionForLinux` is Succeeded, I should consider it as encrypted?

Comment: no, its only provisioned the extension, after that it starts encrypting the vm. use this `Get-AzureRmVmDiskEncryptionStatus  -ResourceGroupName $rgname -VMName $vmName` to get status

Comment: I am using Azure CLi to check the encryption status `az vm encryption show --resource-group $rgname --name $vmName --query [osDisk] -o tsv` and it shows `EncryptionInProgress`

Comment: Removing the `microsoft-graph` tag. This isn't related to the Microsoft Graph API.

Comment: My VM uses SSD. Should I wait that long time for this too?

Comment: 1 hour roughly for ssd, well depending on the size of the disk

Comment: So, after 1 hour (wait time), the encryption status will show encryption completed?

Comment: @SantoshGhimire Hi, could you get encryption setting with API now? I test in my lab, I could use API to get the information, you could check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I create VM using following command.

```
az vm create \
    --resource-group shuivm \
    --name shuivm \
    --image Canonical:UbuntuServer:16.04-LTS:latest \
    --admin-username azureuser \
    --generate-ssh-keys
```

When I use the following API, I could get encryption setting.

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/**********/resourceGroups/shuivm/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/shuivm?api-version=2017-03-30"
```

[image]

Note: When OS is encrypted  successful, I could use API to get encryption setting.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

This is because there are two types of at-rest disk encryption for Azure VMs and they are not reported in the same part of the Azure Management API:

- **Server-Side Encryption**:  that you can see in the encryptionSettings section of the VM/compute API when you get a vm details. It will show whether you are encypting with a customer managed key or a platform managed key
- **ADE**:  Azure Disk Encryption is actually a VM extension and so you can find it in the VM Extension API instead.

see:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachineextensions/list